# ImageView drag'n'drop 7.1.1 error

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I have two `ViewGroup`s that contain `ImageView`s only. One `ViewGroup` (`RecyclerView`) is something like a toolbox. Another is a work area (`RelativeLayout`). I need to drag an `ImageView` from the toolbox and drop it to the work area.

I was try to move entire ImageView from one parent to another.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
owner.removeView(view);
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) layoutview;
container.addView(view);
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
break;
```

And this works fine on Android below 7.1.1 with February updates. But with 7.1.1 Feb I have an exception:

> ClassCastException: android.widget. RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams

It occurs in `view.setVisibility()`. In the debugger I can see, that after drop, `ImageView` has `RelativeLayout` in parent and `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` in layoutParams. But when the view calls its `setVisibility`, then `RecycleView` layouting runs.

Why this exception throws only on 7.1.1 February update? And what should I do? Maybe I should move only data not entire view? But than I have to create a new `ImageView` in work area.

**UPD:** Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.alexander.example, PID: 20588
                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getChildViewHolderInt(RecyclerView.java:4226)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoForItem(RecyclerView.java:9406)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.java:90)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:246)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:66)
                                                                   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6607)
                                                                   at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6568)
                                                                   at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:23638)
                                                                   at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6551)
                                                                   at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
                                                                   at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
                                                                   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:6505)
                                                                   at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:23550)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:97)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:192)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:432)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:241)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:61)
                                                                   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:6491)
                                                                   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:6358)
                                                                   at android.view.View$AccessibilityDelegate.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:23489)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs.java:122)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateIcsImpl.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:223)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:371)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompat.java:268)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean.java:87)
                                                                   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:6341)
                                                                   at android.view.View$SendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(View.java:23675)
                                                                   at android.view.View$SendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent.runOrPost(View.java:23708)
                                                                   at android.view.View.notifyViewAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded(View.java:9475)
                                                                   at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:11591)
                                                                   at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:8069)
                                                                   at android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.java:1551)
                                                                   at com.alexander.example.CustomRelativeLayout.onDragEvent(CustomRelativeLayout.java:353)
                                                                   at android.view.View.callDragEventHandler(View.java:20901)
                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchDragEvent(View.java:20889)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1441)
                                                                   at com.alexander.example.CustomRelativeLayout.dispatchDragEvent(CustomRelativeLayout.java:275)
```

Comment: try adding it with new LayoutParams

Comment: `ImageView` removed from `RecyclerView` and added to `RelativeLayout`, so this view already has `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` (I've checked it in the debugger). Anyway I've tried to set new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, it doesn't make any effect. I even tried to set new `RecyclerView.LayoutParams`, then I've got cast exception `RecyclerView$LayoutParams` to `RelativeLayout$LayoutParams`.

Comment: that looks like a bug in Android SDK this way. If you have installed Android msources, you can set breakpoint inside Android code, and see what is wrong there, and if the layoutparams are really wrong

Comment: I tried to understand the source code. I understood only that `View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo` calls `AccessibilityDelegateCompat$AccessibilityDelegateJellyBeanImpl$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo` that calls `RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate$1.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo`. (Should it calls JellyBean delegate at all???)

While `ImageView`'s parent and `LayoutParams` belong to `RelativeLayout` all the way. See updated post with stacktrace.